# Equivalent to pickle in Julia

Tags: serialization, julia

I'm looking for a convenient way to dump and load variables in Julia, just like pickle does in Python.

Is there a package which does something like `myVar = load(myPath)` and `dump(myVar, myPath)` (or similarly `f = open(myPath, "r"); myVar = load(f)`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the HDF5 package has the functionality you want, it worked very good for me using some custom types and all:

see here:

https://github.com/JuliaLang/HDF5.jl

Answer (score 9):

[HDF5.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/HDF5.jl) package have been split into HDF5 new package and JLD

see here:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/JLD.jl

Saving and loading julia variables while preserving native types is now possible using JLD

According doc:

> JLD, for which files conventionally have the extension .jld, is a
>   widely-used format for data storage with the Julia programming
>   language. JLD is a specific "dialect" of HDF5, a cross-platform,
>   multi-language data storage format most frequently used for scientific
>   data. By comparison with "plain" HDF5, JLD files automatically add
>   attributes and naming conventions to preserve type information for
>   each object.